# Handling forms with types

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Is there anyway to set types in react hook forms? Everything is returned as string, even the time picker.

[image]

Would be nice if the object would be a number if type was a number etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that natively the form fields being managed for dates and numbers all return strings.

```
document.getElementById('my-date-field').value //=> "2020-03-26" (as a string)
```

So it's up to you to convert that according to your application logic. I typically do this in the submit handler:

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit((formData) => {
   const myDate = new Date(formDate.date)
   api.doSomethingWithData(myDate)
})
```